# React conditional re-rendered not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

**Edit**
The issue was a condition I have not noticed in the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method. So please check this if you encounter any issues such as mine.
**Edit**

I've pretty much reached an impasse, and I do not understand why a simple conditional re-rendering this not working.

I have the following state

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
 showConflicts: false
}
```

I want to switch the component based on the parameter that I have in state so I have this button:

```
 <Icon
              icon={"info-sign"}
              intent={"primary"}
              onClick={this.handleShowConflict}
            />
```

which triggers this

```
  handleShowConflict = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      showConflicts: !this.state.showConflicts
    })
  }
```

Upon clicking on the button the state updates properly.

But my component does not change. Just wrote a dummy bellow of what I have:

```
            {
              this.state.showConflicts?
            
               <ConflictTab
                 scrollTo={this.handleConflictScrollTo}
                 data={this.state.conflicts}
               />
              : <Icon
              icon={"info-sign"}
              intent={"primary"}
              onClick={this.handleShowConflict}
            />
            }
```

I've spent way too much time on this, I am not sure why but my code is not re-rendered.

I have a bunch of similar implementations on this project and they are working fine, on set-state this is re-rendered, but on this specific component it is not.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is isConflictsUpdated ?

Comment: I don't see, where are you updating `this.state.isConflictsUpdated`?

Comment: My bad.. I've wrote the code manually now, mispelled, should be this.state.showConflicts

Comment: Whenever using previous state to derive new state value always better to use this : this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {  showConflicts: prevState.showConflicts }
    }). Setting state is async and you should not rely on state values.

Comment: Is Icon a custom component made by you? `onClick` might not work like that

Comment: @TusharShahi I will try using prevstate, only issue is that I've manually set the flag as true and still did not work through my many tests :). And no, the Icon is a blueprintjs imported component. Currently my damn environment refuses to load the page.

Comment: @TusharShahi still not working.. same behaviour state is updated component not re-rendered,     this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { showConflicts: !prevState.showConflicts };
    });
  };

Comment: f it still does not work, can you provide a codesandbox example? Or maybe try to notice what you are doing different on this apge

Comment: @TusharShahi https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-tdd-8lo4q?file=/src/App.js, but sadly it works in the sandbox... it means I have something that breaks this, I assumed so but I have a pretty huge component and I can't replicate it in the sandbox. Any idea what might impact this specific re-render? I do not have any conditions on render(like using the useEffect hook for specific elements), nor am I triggering any other setstate on this button

Comment: @TusharShahi, goddamn... I've found the issue. Thanks for the help! Our convo helped me track a small condition I had in the shouldComponentUpdate that broke my re-render...

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing state within setState. Try resolving that issue and see if it works

```
  handleShowConflict = (e) => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      showConflicts: !prev.showConflicts
    }))
  }
```

this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Sadly, it did not work, this the code change I've done,     this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { isConflictsUpdated: !prevState.isConflictsUpdated };
    });
  };

Comment: Oh well, sorry about that.. maybe you could provide a running example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-tdd-8lo4q?file=/src/App.js, but sadly it works in the sandbox, I can't replicate my whole component, it's huge, any idea what could impact this? I am not doing any other setstates when I click on that button